# Web API2 authentication against a REST service

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

We would like to use the new authorization/token system of Web API2 and have upgraded to MVC5/Web API2.

There is an internal REST API that does authentication already that we would like to reuse. Essentially it takes uid/pwd and some additional profile parameters and returns true/false.

Question: how to hook up an authentication filter against that service instead of the default Entity Framework 6 DB-based Identity store?

I looked at UserManager class and it is unclear this is the right path.

Comment: There was a brief mentioning of authentication against web service in Daniel Roth's Web API 2.0 video, but he did not go into details.

Comment: Can you clarify how you want the authentication filter to work? Do you want to use the Basic authentication scheme, or some other mechanism? (How does the username/password get provided to the filter.)

Comment: Create VS2013 New Single Page Application Project. Review Providers folder, App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs, App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs And if you still fill confused understand OWIN Authentication.

Comment: Figured it out: The built-in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs has a nice integration point, GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(), which has username/password in the context parameter. Inside, I plugged in our authentication web service call-out, and only allow entry added to DB and token issued if the call succeeds with a valid user.  The issue with the scheme is we are low in the stack with the Entity Framework implementation and thus have to use a DB. @dmatson, we switched from BA against a web service to token-based auth. And to jd4u: thanks, but the token issuing part was of my most concern.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following video answer your question.
http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/webapi-v2-security